# How to unpublish multiple posts in one click?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I need to unpublish 200 posts in order to make some hard edition. These posts are from 2012 and my site is live with all the posts since 2013 until today.
I would like to find a solution to be able to bulk unpublish posts of year 2012 in order for our team to edit them. 
If there's no solution by date, the other alternative is to select all the posts and un publish them.
What would be the plugin or solution in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Posts and Filter by month and use the bulk edit feature. Check all posts for the month and change the status to Draft.

You can use the Screen Options to display any number of posts per page on the Posts screen.

More http://codex.wordpress.org/Posts_Screen

Comment: How can I missed this?:)It's an existing feature...

Comment: This takes too long if you have 600.000 posts (as I do), spread over some 12 years...